# Update Audacious under Xenial?

Tags: 16.04, updates, audacious

Xenial Xerus has Audacious 3.6.2 which was released more than a year ago on May 30th, 2015. I would like to use the latest Audacious: 3.7.2 released on March 28th, 2016. How can I get the latest version?

Comment: Did you try to install it following the installation instructions provided in the source package that you can [download from the website](http://audacious-media-player.org/download)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add WebUpd8's PPA at https://launchpad.net/~nilarimogard/+archive/ubuntu/webupd8, which provides Audacious 3.7.2 (and plugins too) for Ubuntu 16.04:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```